# What's a Good Word Meaning "Vaguely Interested In"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The title says it all and there's very little context: today I wanted to describe something I have a vague interest in.

> He is **vaguely interested in** the study of hex editing but has yet found the time to look into the subject at any length.

Comment: I guess it's safe to assume that you aren't satisfied with the answer "fascinated"? I have another question about the word you want. You say you want a word that can replace "vaguely interested in." Does the "in" part have to be included in the single word, or are you OK with suggestions that consist of an adjective or participle plus a preposition, such as "fascinated with/by"?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a single word, but you might be vaguely interested in the expression "bemused by"?

Comment: @Chappo isn't bemused just a fancy were of saying confused?

Comment: @suməlic the 'in' doesn't need to be included. I guess you could rephrase as a  'mild(ly)/vague(ly) interest(ed)'.

Comment: "Bemused" has a second meaning, which I thought was something like "lightly distracted", but Dictionary.com says it means *lost in thought* or *preoccupied*. Not the right word after all!

Comment: @suməlic 'fascinated' has the connotation of a greater interest than I wish to convey.

Answer (score 1):

Probably ***[browsing](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/browse)*** comes close to the idea you want to convey:

> - ***to look through a book or magazine without reading everything,*** or to walk around a shop looking at several things without intending to buy any of them. (Cambridge Dictionary)

- He is just browsing through the study of hex editing but has not yet found the time to look into the subject at any length.

Comment: 'He is browsing the study of hex editing...' - does that sound right?

Answer (score 0):

I like the word intrigued.

He was intrigued by the study of hex editing but has yet found the time to look into the subject at any length.

or

He had a passing interest in hex editing but has yet found the time to look into the subject at any length.

or

He had heard of hex editing but has yet found the time to look into the subject at any length.

Comment: 'intrigued' implies a greater interest than I wish to convey.